# Select 'Partial Document'

Tags: mongodb

In the [tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial#Tutorial-SpecifyingWhattheQueryReturns), there is an example:

> SELECT j FROM things WHERE x=4

The returned document gave just the "j" elements.

What if I want to return "j" element of all the documents (`SELECT j FROM things`)?

Comment: See also http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart

Comment: Here is the documentation on that question:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection

Answer (score 4):

Provide an empty filter/match expression:

```
db.things.find({}, {j:true})
```

Comment: darn, had I not chosen to drink that coffee, maybe I'd have been faster ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use an empty query:

`db.things.find({}, {j:true}).forEach(printjson);`